# Why WebGL constrains the maximum dimensions instead of the raw size of an image?

Tags: javascript, webgl, video-card

Why WebGL's *MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE* property constraints the maximum dimensions of an image instead of its raw size in pixels?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("webgl-canvas")
gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
var maxTextureSize = gl.getParameter( gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE );

console.log("Max texture size: ", maxTextureSize)
```

```html
<canvas id="webgl-canvas" width="1" height="1"></canvas>
```

So when the *MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE* is *N* it means the maximum texture possible is uniform (width = *N* and height = *N*). Why can't one use a texture with arbitrary proportions with the pixel size *N^2*.

This problem is elegantly [handled](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/e0bd5d5785eab924593f51d02d6213b7675ae50f/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLTextures.js#L15) by [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js), but I am coruius about the theoretical background.

My guess: it would make some texture operations impossible. However I hope someone here has a specific answer.

#### Update:

As tkausl pointed out this limit is not a novel property of the WebGL standard, but of some underlying abstraction like the driver or the very architecture of the video card.

Comment: This is a limitation of the graphics card/graphics driver, not of WebGL

Comment: @tkausl I guessed, but my code example is in JavaScript. So I tried to stay in that domain, but your are right I will update my  question.